# Sending file to distant FTP server

Tags: c, sockets, ftp, network-programming, recv

I have a task "Send file to distant FTP server". I have written code, but it's not working correctly. I create a socket for data transferring and try to upload my file. After uploading the file, I want to check the server answer using `recv()`, but my program hangs at this moment, but I can see my file on server. If I remove `recv()` from my code, the size of my file is 0 bytes. I have been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days. Can anyone help me?

I'm using this FTP server for testing: ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/

```c
int upload_file(char *filename) {
    char str[256];
    char buff[1024];
    int getFile;
    int bytes_read;

    //ds - for data

    sprintf(str, "CWD %s\r\n", "upload");
    send(s, str, strlen(str), 0);
    get_server_answer();
    switch_to_passive_mode();
    sprintf(str, "TYPE I\r\n");
    send(s, str, strlen(str), 0);
    get_server_answer();
    sprintf(str, "STOR %s\r\n", filename);
    send(s, str, strlen(str), 0);
    get_server_answer();

    getFile = open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0644);
    while (1) {
        bytes_read = read(getFile, buff, 1024);
        if (bytes_read <= 0)
            break;
        send(ds, buff, bytes_read, 0);
    }
    char tmp[256];
    recv(s, tmp, 256, MSG_WAITALL); // program hangs here

    close(getFile);
    close(ds);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SteffenUllrich look again more carefully. Presumably `switch_to_passive_mode()` sends a `PASV` command. And the commands are being sent using a socket `s`, but the file data is being sent using a different socket `ds`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You are right. I've completely missed these details. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, FTP data transfers operate in `STREAM` transmission mode. In that mode, after sending the file data over your `ds` socket, you need to close the `ds` socket to signal End-Of-File to the server, *before* attempting to read the server's answer (why are you not using `get_server_answer()` instead?).  Since you are not doing that, you are waiting for a final server answer that is never being sent.

When you remove the `recv()`, you are closing both the `ds` and `s` sockets. By closing the `s` socket without sending a `QUIT` command first, the server thinks your client has vanished unexpectedly before receiving the server's answer, and so it aborts the transfer.

So, you need to either:

- close `ds` (but not `s`!) *after* your loop is finished, but *before* you read the answer.
- use the `MODE` command to switch the data connection's transmission mode to `BLOCK` or `COMPRESSED` mode, which don't signal EOF by closing the data connection.  See [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) Section 3.4 for more details.

Also, you are not validating that the initial answer to the `STOR` command is successful (has a reply code of 125 or 150) before sending the file data over `ds`

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's really helped me. Marked your answer as correct